# Update SQL Server table with local data

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access-2010

I have a project to create an application in Access 2010 that will use a local table to collect data with a tablet (that does not have wireless where data is being collected from) and then when they get back to location that has wireless connectivity to be able to upload the data.

I have the SQL Server database and tables.  Designed the application using linked tables, then converted them to local tables, so I know the design is the same on both.

What is the simplest way to update the sql server tables with the info from the local tables?

Comment: Will the data be a straight upload - an append, in Access terms - or will it need to do updates?  If updates, will the logic be simple (replace the following fields) or complex (for each record, if this do A else do B, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the most straightforward approach would be to keep the linked tables in the Access application so you would have both local tables (e.g., [Stuff]) and linked tables (e.g. [dbo_Stuff]). When the network connection is available you could use [Append queries](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/add-records-to-a-table-by-using-an-append-query-HA010341485.aspx) and/or [Update queries](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/change-existing-data-by-using-an-update-query-HP005188088.aspx) to copy the data from the local tables to the linked tables.

Comment: Would that through any errors when starting the application, when network connection isn't available, if the linked tables source isn't available?

Comment: No. The mere existence of a linked table in Access will not cause errors if the target database is unavailable. You will only get errors if you try to *use* the linked table. That is when Access will try (and fail) to contact the target. A related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2156244/2144390) suggests ways that your code could test whether or not the SQL Server is available before trying to use it.